# How to convert RijndaelManaged AES 256 encryption from C# into PHP using openssl_encrypt

Tags: c#, php, encryption, openssl

I need to integrate an API built in C# into my PHP application. I've been given an example of how to encrypt a token to send via an Authorization header, however I'm having difficulty converting the C# code into PHP. Any help would be appreciated. I'm attempting to use openssl_encrypt as mcrypt is deprecated. Example C# code below:

```
public static string EncryptData(string textData, string Encryptionkey)
{
    RijndaelManaged objrij = new RijndaelManaged();
    //set the mode for operation of the algorithm
    objrij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //set the padding mode used in the algorithm.
    objrij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    //set the size, in bits, for the secret key.
    objrij.KeySize = 0x80;
    //set the block size in bits for the cryptographic operation.
    objrij.BlockSize = 0x80;
    //set the symmetric key that is used for encryption & decryption.
    byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encryptionkey);
    //set the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm
    byte[] EncryptionkeyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    int len = passBytes.Length;
    if (len > EncryptionkeyBytes.Length)
    {
        len = EncryptionkeyBytes.Length;
    }
    Array.Copy(passBytes, EncryptionkeyBytes, len);

    objrij.Key = EncryptionkeyBytes;
    objrij.IV = EncryptionkeyBytes;

    //Creates a symmetric AES object with the current key and initialization vector IV.
    ICryptoTransform objtransform = objrij.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] textDataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textData);
    //Final transform the test string.
    return Convert.ToBase64String(objtransform.TransformFinalBlock(textDataByte, 0, textDataByte.Length));
}
```

I have tried a number of different approaches, but as a base point, this is what I currently have:

```
// Encryption key provided is 44 bytes/characters:
$key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
// Data/Header to encrypt:
$dataToEncrypt = $user . $datetime;
// IV for AES-256-CBC is 16 bytes/characters:
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC'));
// Encrypt token:
$token = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
// Base 64 encode:
$token = base64_encode($iv . $token);
```

Comment: The C# code uses a 16 bytes key (and truncates longer keys). So the PHP code must use AES-128 accordingly. Also, the C# code also uses the key as an IV (which is generally insecure).  In the PHP code, a randomly generated IV is used and prepended to the ciphertext, which is actually the more secure way, but just doesn't match the C# code.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for your reply. I've got it working off the back of your comment. If you'd like to submit an answer I'd happily mark it as correct. I did wonder why the IV matched the key, I'll forward that note onto the dev team looking after the API as a possible security improvement.